# How to use a ContentPresenter inside a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, contentpresenter

I'd like to create a UserControl (in this case a square-Button with defined Backgroundcolors) which can host it's own content.

UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SGDB.UI.Controls.ModernButton"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SGDB.UI.Controls"
         xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:SGDB.UI.Converter"
         x:Name="_modernButton">
<Button>
    <Button.Resources>
        <converter:EnumToColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
    </Button.Resources>
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border Width="{Binding Size, ElementName=_modernButton}" Height="{Binding Size, ElementName=_modernButton}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.8,0.8,3,3">
                <Grid Background="{Binding BackgroundColor, ElementName=_modernButton, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Now, as you may expect it, if I use this Control inside my MainView everthing works just fine until I define some Content.

Using:

```
<control:ModernButton Size="200" BackgroundColor="Light">
    TEST
</control:ModernButton>
```

In this case "TEST" will override the whole Content of the UserControl (the whole Button Template). I guess this happens because The Button inside the UserControl is defined as "Content" itself and it will get overridden when defining new Content.

So the final question is: Is it possible to achieve what I'm looking for? if yes: How? How could I "redirect" the Content I'm defining in my MainView into the self-defined ContentPresenter inside my Button Template instead of the UserControls's ContentPresenter?

If possible I don't want to create a new dp-propery which hosts my Content, e.g.:

```
<controls:MordernButton Size="200" BackgroundColor="Light">
    <controls:ModernButton.Content>
        I don't want this, if possible
    </controls:ModernButton.Content>
</controls:ModernButton>
```

Comment: You mean you don't want to create new dp for this?

Comment: Correct - if possible, of course.

Comment: @Chill-X See my answer below.  Let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here we go.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SGDB.UI.Controls.ModernButton"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SGDB.UI.Controls"
     xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:SGDB.UI.Converter"
     x:Name="_modernButton">

    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Button Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                 <Button.Resources>
                    <converter:EnumToColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
                  </Button.Resources>
            <Button.Template >
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Width="{Binding Size,
                                    ElementName=_modernButton}"
                    Height="{Binding Size,
                                     ElementName=_modernButton}"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="0.8,0.8,3,3">
                        <Grid Background="{Binding BackgroundColor, ElementName=_modernButton, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: At first it seemed very good - but when passing some Content ("TEST" or <TextBlock Text="Test"/>) nothing shows up - the Control stays empty (except it's own color)

Comment: That's it - could you explain why the Button's TargetType had such an big impact on the ContentPresenter ? And if you are on it, maybe you could explain why the Button's Templatebinding stops WPF from clearing the whole Content when passing some Content into a Control? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That will be a big topic to cover.  May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3632926/2819451) answers your first question.

Comment: To answer you second question.  Its not Button's template binding that helps us to stop clearing the whole content.  Its Usercontrol's template binding did its job.

Answer (score 27):

Use the `ContentPropertyAttribute` to instruct the xaml to set this property instead of the actual Content property.

```
[ContentProperty("InnerContent")]
public partial class ModernButton : UserControl
{
    public ModernButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InnerContent", typeof(object), typeof(ModernButton));

    public object InnerContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(InnerContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InnerContentProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml, Bind the Content Presenter to use InnerContent property instead.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding InnerContent, ElementName=_modernButton}"/>
```

This way you can do the following without replacing the actual content.

```
<control:ModernButton Size="200" BackgroundColor="Light">
    TEST
</control:ModernButton>
```

Comment: Works, too. But I wanted to know how things work in XAML - I really don't like decorating Code with Attributes.

Comment: Awesome tip! since it isn't a template override, you are allowed to define names and links with code behind easily

Comment: Where does _modernButton come from?

Comment: @Glaucus That's what OP named his UserControl as.

Comment: After trying to make a custom titled frame, this really does seem to be the best solution. I did learn a lot of other stuff, though, which makes hosting various forms of content more dynamic. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Let's assume that youre UserControl is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="QuickAndDirtyAttempt.Decorator" ....
      <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Decorator}">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label>Foo</Label>
            <ContentPresenter/>
            <Label>Bar</Label>
          </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Note the TargetType property on the template: without it the project will happily compile, but the ContentPresenter will not work.
And then:

```
<Window ... >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <local:Decorator>
            <Label Background="Wheat">User supplied content here</Label>
        </local:Decorator>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I strongly recommend you to [read this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82464/How-to-Embed-Arbitrary-Content-in-a-WPF-Control) before implementing anything

Comment: I read this but over read the part that says: "Without the TargetType the Project will happily compile but the ContentPresenter won't work". You deserve my upvote because the CodeProject explains why one should not use my solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple; Just circumvent and replace the UserControl's Template.

```
  <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
            <Button Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}">
                <Button.Resources>
                   <converter:EnumToColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>
                </Button.Resources>
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Width="{Binding Size,
                                        ElementName=_modernButton}"
                        Height="{Binding Size,
                                         ElementName=_modernButton}"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="0.8,0.8,3,3">
                            <Grid Background="{Binding BackgroundColor, ElementName=_modernButton, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
```

All a user control is (at least it terms of XAML and its template), is a Border with a ContentPresenter inside it. The ContentPresenter being the only important part, really.

So all you do is gut out its Template and feed the Content property the UserControl has into something a little different; in this case, your button.

This is the difference between making a usercontrol **out of** other controls, and shoving some controls **into** a user control.
Making the usercontrol out of other controls gives you much more power.

Comment: Think this could work also if the second ControlTemplate's Type would be "Button".

Comment: Oh yes, how did I miss that? - Edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

My example for dialog box

```
<UserControl
x:Class="CyberpunkModManager.Controls.DialogBox"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CyberpunkModManager.Controls"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
d:DesignHeight="450"
d:DesignWidth="800"
Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeForeground}"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource ThemeTransparentColor}">
            <Border
                MinWidth="400"
                Padding="12"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Background="{StaticResource ThemeElement}"
                CornerRadius="4">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```