# WPF (C#) Usercontrol remove elements

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am making a template using Usercontrol in WPF(C#).

However, when applying this user control, is it possible to subtract a specific part? For example, removing a button?

Comment: Make that extra part hidden

Comment: How can I make it hidden, and how can I make it occur?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are just trying to hide an existing button, which you should do by setting `Visibility` to `Visibility.Collapsed` or `Visibility.Hidden`. This should be done through a  binding to the ViewModel of your user control.

If you need a pure XAML solution: No it is not possible as such. However, the reverse is possible: [you can add content to a user control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36447492/9884514), and that effectively provides the same functionality.

What you could do is make a base user control that doesn't contain the button, and instead has a content presenter. A second user control could wrap the base user control and define a button as its content. Then when you don't want to use the user control with the button you can simply create an instance of the base user control.

Answer (score -1):

To substract specific parts from UserControl, Visibility (Collapse, Hidden) option can be used.
Make sure to add dependency property in UserControl for Visibility to show & hide specific part.

Comment: I don't think it's good advice to add a dependency property to the User Control to control visibility. WPF is built around MVVM, and the MVVM solution is to control the visibility would be through a binding to the view model.

Comment: @NigelBess I don't agree with you, User Controls must exposed necessary functionality to interact with them,..

Comment: The necessary functionality is already exposed through binding. No need to complicate things by adding dependency properties for everything you want to control. Besides, you will still need to access the dependency property, which you should do through a binding either way