# Is it possible to set child controls properties in a user control without code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a sample UserControl I snagged from somewhere and I'm using it to try and understand the capabilities of UserControls.  What I'm trying to do is set properties of the embedded controls (say, txtInput from the UserControl below) in the window xaml.

I know that I can define new properties in the UserControl code (and have done so, see below), but with the UserControl defined as is, can a user of the control txtInput set some random properties, like say FontSize in xaml without me having to have defined FontSize as a property of the UserControls.  Something like:

```
<uc:LimitedInputUserControl x:Name="liucDescription" Title="Enter description:" InitialText="Enter text here" MaxLength="140" Grid.Row="1">
    <txtInput FontSize=20/>
</uc:LimitedInputUserControl>
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestBed.UserControls.LimitedInputUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBed"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid x:Name="grdGrid">
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.5" Color="Orange" />
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="lblTitle" Content="{Binding Title}" />
        <Label x:Name="lblLength" Grid.Column="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=txtInput, Path=Text.Length}" />
                <TextBlock Text="/" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MaxLength}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtInput" MaxLength="{Binding MaxLength}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code is as follows:

```
namespace TestBed.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for LimitedInputUserControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LimitedInputUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public LimitedInputUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        private string sInitialText;
        public string InitialText { get => sInitialText;
            set
            {
                sInitialText = value;
                txtInput.Text = value;
                txtInput.SelectAll();
            }
        }

        public int MaxLength { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `UserControl` inherits from `Control`, so you can just do `<uc:LimitedInputUserControl FontSize="20" />` and this will set the fontsize for all your elements inside the user control. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes and no.  I mean it solves the specific issue presented, but I was more driving towards wanting to be able to set arbitrary properties in the elements inside the UserControl including things that wouldn't be part of the base Control.  Without being able to do that it would mean that I need to decide ahead of time for any user of my UserControl what properties they'd be able to change (via creating properties in the UserControl itself), which would suck.

Comment: If you do not know which properties you want to be able to change, you probably don't want to use a user control. A user control is so you can group together a fixed set of elements that can be reused together. The only other option is to create a user control that can host its own content, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446440/how-to-use-a-contentpresenter-inside-a-usercontrol). Then you can specify the content you want to host and set the properties how you want.